# update from select result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I tried to update the color in table `tbl` of colors in the item table based on field `item_id`, with the following query. but I get an error `Sql error (1242)`.

```
update tbl mt
left join tbl_detail dt on mt.tbl_No = dt.tbl_No 
set dt.color_Id = 
(
    select p.color_ID
    from ( select dt.item_Id, dt.color_Id 
            from tbl mt
                left join tbl_detail dt on mt.tbl_No = dt.tbl_No 
             where mt.Tipe = 2 ) h
    left join itemp on h.item_id = p.item_id
) 
where mt.Tipe = 2 ;
```

I want to update a field color in the table tbl with existing color in the item table. How I should make it?

I have tried a simple syntax like this but then I get `sql error (1442)`

```
update tbl mt 
   left join tbl_detail dt on mt.tbl_No = dt.tbl_No 
   left join item p on dt.item_Id = p.item_Id 
set dt.color_Id = p.color_id 
where mt.Tipe = 2 ;
```

Example :

**table tbl:**

```
|tbl_No|tipe|
   1     2  
   2     2
   3     2
```

**table tbl_detail:**

```
|tbl_detail_No|tbl_No|item_id|color_id|
        1         1      1     null
        2         1      2     null
        1         2      3     null
        2         2      4     null
```

**table item:**

```
|item_id|color_id|
     1       1
     2       2
     3       3
     4       4
```

I want to update `color_id` in table `tbl_detail` based on `item_id` in table `item`; after the update, the table `tbl_detail` should be as follows.

**table tbl_detail:**

```
|tbl_detail_No|tbl_No|item_id|color_id|
        1         1      1       1
        2         1      2       2
        1         2      3       3
        2         2      4       4
```

(oh, I'm really bad at explaining it, hope someone can understand as English is not my first language.)
Thanks for all the help and advice.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I dont know how to explain it, I just want to update field color in table 'tbl' with content of field color in table item.

Comment: What are all the other tables for?

Comment: I need the tipe of table tbl field as conditions for updating

Comment: I have tried a simple syntax like this but to no avail.

Comment: <code> update tbl mt
left join tbl_detail dt on mt.tbl_No = dt.tbl_No 
left join item p on dt.item_Id = p.item_Id
set dt.color_Id = p.color_id
where dt.item_Id = p.item_Id and mt.Tipe = 2 ;<code>

Comment: select top 1 pcolord_id etcetc?

Comment: but I want to update all data based on item_id.